# Maven install transitive dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-install-plugin

I have a project, and I need to install a library on Maven so that I can use it on said project. The problem I ran into is that said library, say libA, has a dependency itself, libB,  which is also a third party one.

I have added both to my local repository by using this code:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=VerBDConverter.jar -DgroupId=verbdconverter
-DartifactId=verbdconverter -Dversion=1.00 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Did the same for the lib 2. Problem is that, when I go to my project's pom and add the < dependency > for libA, Maven is not picking up libB.

**Question**: It should be, after all, Maven should get libA's dependencies, but it didn't.

Comment: It might help if you specifically list the names of your dependencies on this question, in case it's something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052763/downloading-lwjgl-natives-with-ivy) going on... We normally need to be able to reproduce the issue before we can help.

Comment: @andrew, thanks, the reason i did not include both libs names was because they were created by my own company, and thus are not available on the Maven repository.

Comment: Since this is in an corporate setting, you should look into setting up an artifact repository (like Artifactory or Nexus) to host your company's custom libraries.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> It should be, after all, Maven should get libA's dependencies, but it didn't.

No, in your case Maven will not know out of the blue which transitive dependencies libA would require, because libA was manually installed and there is no trace of libB anywhere.

Normally, transitive dependencies are dependencies defined in the `dependencies` section of the `.pom` file available as part of a deployed application. The `.pom` file is essentially a copy of the original `pom.xml` file, renamed to reflect the library name (i.e. `artifactId-version.jar`, then `artifactId-version.pom`).

When resolving a dependency, maven will also check its `.pom` file and as such get information about its dependencies (which become transitive dependencies) and build (and fetch) the required dependencies graph for it (that is, re-iterate the same process for each and every declared dependency).

From official [Maven - Introduction to the dependency mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

> This feature is facilitated by reading the **project files** of your dependencies from the remote repositories specified. In general, all dependencies of those projects are used in your project, as are any that the project inherits from its parents, or from its dependencies, and so on.

Note: bold is mine. *project files* are normally the `pom.xml` files, renamed into `*.pom` files once related artifacts are uploaded to a Maven repository (or installed into the local Maven cache).

---

From your question, you used `-DgeneratePom=true`, hence you didn't pass libA' `pom.xml` file, but a new one was [automatically generated](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#generatePom)

> Generate a minimal POM for the artifact if none is supplied via the parameter `pomFile`. Defaults to `true` if there is no existing POM in the local repository yet.

The autogenerated `.pom` file will be almost empty (Maven coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version) but no `dependencies` section in it), hence Maven will treat libA as library with no transitive dependencies: it cannot find any, it cannot guess neither.

---

You hence have four solutions (in order of recommendation):

- In corporate environment, set-up an [enterprise Maven repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) (like Arifactory, Nexus or Apache Archivia) and properly deploy these libraries to it, or
- Re-install libA using the [`pomFile`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#pomFile) option, or
- Manually add the `dependencies` section to the generated `.pom` file and add libB to it, or
- Explicitly declare libB in your consumer `pom.xml` file

---

For further reading on SO:

- [Why Maven is looking for .pom file when .jar is present in the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795427/why-maven-is-looking-for-pom-file-when-jar-is-present-in-the-repository)

Answer (score -4):

This may help you:

```
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.jdbc -DartifactId=sqljdbc1 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.jdbc -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc41.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.jdbc -DartifactId=sqljdbc41 -Dversion=4.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Source: https://github.com/Programmercito/osbo-framework/blob/master/libs/instala.bat