# How to add local Maven package jar files to a Maven project

Tags: java, maven, or-tools

## Summary

When using `maven-install-plugin:install-file` to install maven jar package all dependencies are ignored and this plugin write a dumb/broken pom file.

## Context

I have a local Maven package jar file `foo-java-1.2.3.jar` which contains its own pom.xml in `META-INF/maven/org.mizux.foo/foo-java/pom.xml` with few dependencies

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mizux.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-linux-x86-64</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then, I tried to install it locally using:

```sh
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file -Dfile=foo-java.1.2.3.jar
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file -Dfile=foo-linux-x86-64.1.2.3.jar
```

ref: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

note: `net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform` and `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java` can be found on maven central...

Then when using it in a `Bar` project `pom.xml`:

```xml
...
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mizux.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

while `mvn compile` pass ?

I can't run my `Bar's main` since all transitive dependencies of foo-java are not passed to Bar so I got some `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

```sh
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.mizux.bar.Test"
...
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Platform
```

Looking at `~/.m2/repository/org/mizux/foo/foo-java/1.2.3/foo-java-1.2.3.pom` this one seems to only contains the minimum (groupID, artifactID...) but the whole dependencies part is not present !!

**questions**:

- How I can install local maven jar package so the pom installed is the full one and not a truncated version.
- Why install plugin generate this dummy pom while the complete one is present inside the jar artifact ?

note: When using `mvn install` on a local build of foo-java the pom exported in `.m2` is vastly different i.e. it's a copy of the foo-java original pom.xml !
i.e.

```sh
%diff ~/.m2/repository/org/mizux/foo/foo-java/1.2.3/foo-java-1.2.3.pom .../foo-java/pom.xml
```

note2: here a github project to reproduce the issue
https://github.com/Mizux/java-ortools you can take a look at action to see a full log https://github.com/Mizux/java-ortools/actions on linux/macos/windows and a docker ubuntu container

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559692/maven-install-transitive-dependencies

Comment: @huch well I do not specify `GeneratePom=True` but it may be true by default, thanks i'll dig it

Comment: Could you add the output of the `install:install-file` goal?

Answer (score 0):

Since the feature you are expecting does not work:

Either use the latest version of the plugin (3.0.0-M1) to see if this is fixed

Either run maven in debug (`mvnDebug -X`) and place a break point in the line below; for all that matters, your JAR file is probably broken.

- [At the point where JAR entries are matched](https://github.com/apache/maven-install-plugin/blob/maven-install-plugin-2.5/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/install/InstallFileMojo.java#L223)
- [Where the JAR entries are processed](https://github.com/apache/maven-install-plugin/blob/maven-install-plugin-2.5/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/install/InstallFileMojo.java#L446)
- Since you will have to debug in your IDE, you may also want to clone the GIT repository and switch to the tag as to match the version of the plugin you use.

Either extract the pom manually and pass it.

Comment: no all this information are extracted to the jar itself see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html third cmd, the problem is the maven-install-plugin only extract those and discard all other contents, What I want is the plugin to ALSO copy the pom.xml verbatim

Comment: Well, if that does not work, you've don't have much choice: you have to analyse why this fail.

Answer (score 0):

> Why install plugin generate this dummy pom while the complete one is present inside the jar artifact ?

According to the doc

> Generate a minimal POM for the artifact if none is supplied via the parameter pomFile. Defaults to true if there is no existing POM in the local repository yet.

ref: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#generatePom

Now I don't know if we can force the maven-install-plugin to copy the pom.xml present in the jar file itself (ed which is already parsed by the plugin !!!)

## Ugly workaround

I could extract the pom.xml from the .jar file (which contains it!) then pass it along the jar in the install-file command.

```sh
unzip -j foo-java-1.2.3.jar META-INF/maven/org.mizux.foo/foo-java/pom.xml

mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file \
-Dfile=foo-java-1.2.3.jar -DpomFile=pom.xml

mvn compile

mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.mizux.bar.Bar"
```